# Using jQuery.pageless with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm using jQuery.pageless (for infinite scrolling) on my rails app. (https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless)

Everything works great except when using turbolinks. When using turbolinks, it just defaults to basic will_paginate look. Anything I can change to get this working properly with Turbolinks?

here are a few files

controller:

```
@users = @user.followed_users.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
if request.xhr?
  render :partial => @users
end
```

application helper:

```
def pageless(total_pages, url=nil, container=nil)
  opts = {
    :totalPages => total_pages,
    :url        => url,
    :loaderImage => image_path("load.gif")
  }

  container && opts[:container] ||= container

  javascript_tag("$('.controller-container').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
end
```

view:

```
<%= render(:partial => "user", :collection => @users) %>
<%= will_paginate(@users) %>
<%= pageless(@users.total_pages, user_followers_path(@user)) %>
```

and this is the JS file used: https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js

I know many people have problems with some JavaScript libraries and Turbolinks and I need to find a workaround to get these JS libraries, like jQuery.pageless, to work with Turbolinks...

Thanks

Comment: For me the jqplot started to behave strangely. When I introduced turbolinks. So All the Js need to be reviewed carefully.

Comment: Justin I tried the whole thing on a real customer project and it works well... That means that something is missing. Could you provide the javascript console log please? Maybe there are errors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately pageless cant be used with turbolinks now.
I've patched it to make it work and I'm going to create a pull request later.

https://github.com/amenzhinsky/jquery.pageless/commit/8f7797be3a29612f5aad703b803bef7416fa576a